# when will release or nil variables in ARC?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, ios7, automatic-ref-counting

I have create one class for declaring global variable in my application.

.h file

```
@interface GlobalVariables : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *strTemp1;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *arrTemp1;

+ (GlobalVariables *)sharedInstance ;
```

.m file

```
#import "GlobalVariables.h"

@implementation GlobalVariables

+ (GlobalVariables *)sharedInstance
{
    static GlobalVariables *sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
       sharedInstance = [self new];
        // Do any other initialisation stuff here
        NSLog(@"alloc and intialize");
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}
```

Now in some class, I set the value of this variable.

```
 [[GlobalVariables sharedInstance] setStrTemp1:@"Temp1"];
 [[GlobalVariables sharedInstance] setArrTemp1:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Name",@"Address",@"Contact NO", nil]];
```

and also get this value in other class.

```
NSLog(@"Get string value : %@", [[GlobalVariables sharedInstance] strTemp1]);
NSLog(@"Get arr value : %@", [[GlobalVariables sharedInstance] arrTemp1]);
```

Now my question is when this varibles are release or nil?

I am using ARC in my project.

I know arc will release it automatcally but when and how?

Comment: If you're using ARC, you really shouldn't care when or how it releases its memory.

Comment: before iOS 5 There are no concept of ARC mens you have to release all the object that you create......if you forget any one there a warning show that memory leak.... So after iOS 5 the ARC (Automatic Reference counting)...You alloc your object and forget those without any problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a singleton class and the class with the properties will be live until you finish the app or the app terminate by other reason.

Comment: Or if you assign `nil` to it.

Comment: if you assign nil that means there are no value in that object ... but there are a reference will remain of that object...

Comment: so you have to release that object before ARC to remove reference and For Free memory

Comment: maybe if everything that references it is a `weak` variable, arc will clean it up as expected, but im uncertain.